# Copy Directory Structure with Date File Filter to UNC Share in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

How can I copy all files that match a filter and the directory structure to UNC path will powershell:

For example with the filter as `"*2011_01_02*.bak"`:

```
\arf.2011_01_02.bak
\foo\baz\arf.2011_01_02.bak
```

To `\\192.168.1.1\meow\` with the result of:

```
\\192.168.1.1\meow\arf.2011_01_02.bak
\\192.168.1.1\meow\foo\baz\arf.2011_01_02.bak
```

Comment: It sounds like it's raining cats and dogs over by you guys...

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
Copy-Item . -Destination "\\192.168.1.1\meow\" -Filter "*2011_01_02*.bak" -Recurse
```

(Based on some fiddling on a test box.)

Answer (score 0):

Using robocopy, something like the following does the trick:

```
Robocopy.exe .\ \\192.168.1.1\meow *.ps1 /S
```

Not powershell, but seems to do the trick.